"errorMessage":"Output malformed JSON in oml4py
Why I am receiving a malformed JSON error when running a script in the OML4Py embedded execution from the REST API?
$ curl -i -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' 
-d '{"graphicsFlag":true, "service":"MEDIUM"}' 
"/oml/api/py-scripts/v1/do-eval/myscript"
{"errorMessage":"Output malformed JSON. This could be caused by explicitly calling print() in the executed Python script. Remove print() call from the script should solve the issue.","errorCode":1026}

Please read the description of the ML tag, which also shows up when you add the tag to a question.

The result of a REST API for embedded Python execution function endpoint is a JSON representation of the value returned by the Python function of the specified script. The Python function in the script must return a JSON serializable value. The supported values are the following:
boolean
dict
enum, IntEnum
float
int
list
pandas.DataFrame
str
tuple

PNG images rendered in the script are included in the response. In the JSON returned, the IMAGE field contains the bytes of the PNG image and the DATA field contains the return value of the function.
